# Problems in LazyDataModel. Don't reset the first parameter

Tags: spring, primefaces, jsf-2, lazydatamodel

I have a problem with a *LazyDataModel* (list) in JSF. The problem is the next:

I have a xhtml with a search form and a list of results of that search. I do a first search and show on this pagined list, when I move on about the pages and I have, for example, in the fourth page:

[image]

If I realize a new search, in this new result, the list charge on page 4. The parameter first don't reset in every new search. Why?

[image]

1. The bean has the annotations: *@Component* and *@ViewScoped*.
2. The list with the results is a *LazyDataModel* and overwriting the methods: *load*, *getRowKey* and *getRowData*.
3. The versions are: JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces 6.1 and Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you maintain the same datamodel. You need to create a new datamodel when refresh the list.

For example, the datamodel:

```
public class MyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<MyEntity> {
   // my datamodel
}
```

And the bean (in this case, CDI)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    private MyDataModel myDataModel;

    //calling this method, a new datamodel is created and populated
    public void search() {
        List myList = new ArrayList(); //load from database
        loadDatamodel(myList);  
    }

    private void loadDatamodel(List myList) {               
        myDataModel = new MyDataModel(myList);
    }

    public MyDataModel getMyDataModel() {
        return myDataModel;
    }
}
```

So, in every search, a new datamodel is created.